# Web page launch error

Tags: html

How to go about this error "Launch terminated : ERROR: Course launch was canceled because the HACP getParam failed to find the user information". cannot open the web page beacause of this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you might have left the browser idle for a long time and the session got logged out.

Solution: Login to the Skillport or other Portal which is linked to the Skillport, and everything should be all set.

Answer (score -1):

Please be more specific. Which website? Which browser?

Googling the error (which you should have done first) yields [this result](http://support.inspiredelearning.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2204372-learner-frequently-asked-questions#_Toc7):

> **I get the Skillsoft error: “Launch terminated: ERROR: Course launch was cancelled because the HACP getParam failed to find the user information”:**
>
> Per our Required Browser Settings document, please ensure that *.skillport.com is added to your Trusted Sites zone in Internet Explorer.

If you're not on "skillport.com", whatever it is, you'll probably want to add the domain you're on to the Trusted Sites instead.